# Convert VOC to labelMe

Tags: python, image

Our team uses labelMe for annotating images. I received a batch of annotations that are in VOC format and need to open them in labelMe for review, but am having trouble convert them to the labelMe format.

I can get all the fields that the labelMe json file needs, except for "imageData", which looks like some kind of encoding of the image data. 
I've tried leaving it out, hoping that having the image path would be enough, but I get a imageData error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run **labelme** from the terminal you can add the flag `--nodata`. By doing so you can see what value is put in for the key `imageData`; namely `null`. So substituting `null` for this key should work.

Answer (score 0):

> pip install pascal-voc

```
import json

from pascal import annotation_from_xml

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ann = annotation_from_xml("pascal_voc.xml")
    labelme = ann.to_labelme()
    with open("pascal_ann.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(labelme, f, indent=2)
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answer and provide an explanation. You also could have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).